# Remove quotes in output file generated using vba code

Tags: excel, vba, replace

```
Function TransformLine(sLineData As String) As String

    Dim sOutput As String
    Dim sPre As String
    Dim sPos As String
    Dim iPosV As Integer, iPosDQ As Integer

    iPosV = InStr(1, sLineData, "_V", vbTextCompare)
    If iPosV > 0 Then
        iPosDQ = InStr(iPosV, sLineData, Chr(34), vbTextCompare)
        sPre = Left(sLineData, iPosV - 1)
        sPos = Right(sLineData, Len(sLineData) - iPosDQ + 1)
        sOutput = sPre & sPos
    Else
        iPosDQ = 0
        sOutput = sLineData
    End If

    TransformLine = sOutput

End Function
```

Actual output Now :

```
"01/07/2019|""30/09/2019""|""IGL""|""RC 000000001235 JUL-19 SEP-19""|""IGLCNTLEUR""|""IGLCNTLEUR""|""B03873""|""LARRAIN VIAL ACTIVOS SA""|""0""|""LARRAIN VIAL ACTIVOS SA""|""0""|""LARRAIN VIAL ACTIVOS SA""|""33199_V1""|""FUNDSETTLE EOC NOMINEES LTD A/C FS/BBH FBO 2010858 ADMIN CCHE- CACTIVO REINVEST""|""No""|""2072""|""CC""|""LU0100600369""|""INVESCO GREATER CHINA EQUITY FUND""|""ACC C""|""USD""|4794|0.1|92.33|0|0|""USD""|1|92.33|0|""E""|""20191101""|""""|""PM000000238966"""
```

expected output
I wanted to remove one set of double quotes alone ,as below

```
"01/07/2019"|"30/09/2019"|"IGL"|"RC 000000001235 JUL-19 SEP-19"|"IGLCNTLEUR"|"IGLCNTLEUR"|"B03873"|"LARRAIN VIAL ACTIVOS SA"|"0"|"LARRAIN VIAL ACTIVOS SA"|"0"|"LARRAIN VIAL ACTIVOS SA"|"33199"|"FUNDSETTLE EOC NOMINEES LTD A/C FS/BBH FBO 2010858 ADMIN CCHE- CACTIVO REINVEST"|"No"|"2072"|"CC"|"LU0100600369"|"INVESCO GREATER CHINA EQUITY FUND"|"ACC C"|"USD"|4794|0.1|92.33|0|0|"USD"|1|92.33|0|"E"|"20191101"|""|"PM000000238966"
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, you should only post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And what does your `SaveOutputFile` routine do?

Comment: Hi Ron , save out put file will contain the name and format of the output file  .  Myapologies Sephiroth ,not sure which part to delete ,as I am really new to VBA ,please excuse

Comment: I added the lines below and it has fixed  my problem ,                               If iPosV > 0 Then
        iPosDQ = InStr(iPosV, sLineData, Chr(34), vbTextCompare)
        sPre = Left(sLineData, iPosV - 1)
        sPos = Right(sLineData, Len(sLineData) - iPosDQ + 1)
        sValout = sPre & sPos
        sOutput = Replace(sValout, """""", """")
    Else
        iPosDQ = 0
        sValout = sLineData
        sOutput = Replace(sValout, """""", """")